# Sum of squares calculation

Tags: java

> Write a program that displays the sum of the squares of each integer in the multiplication table. integers 1-10
>   From Professor:The values in the table should be the rowNum squared plus the colNum squared. So, the first entry is 2 (rowNum = 1, colNum = 1. 1^2 + 1^2 = 1 + 1 = 2).  The next entry is 5 (rowNum = 1, colNum = 2. 1^2 + 2^2 = 1 + 4 = 5).

My code won't print anything but the Titles. No calculation. Table should like something like this:

```
    1  2  3   4   5 ....
1   2  5  10  17  26....
2   5  8  13  20  29....
```

```
public class Mobilesumcp3ex3 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    public static void main ( String [] args )
    {
        // Display a title
        System.out.println( " Sum of Multipication Table" );
        System.out.println( "-------------------" );             


        int num[] = new int[10];          
        int sq[] = new int[10];                
        int sum = 0;              
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {                       

            sq[i] = num[i] * num[i];                       
            sum += sq[i];   
        } 
        System.out.println(num+"\t"+sum);
        System.out.println("Sum of the square of numbers: " + sum);    
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem/question here?

Comment: Your answer should be 0, num[] is not  initialized

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I don't think "not initialized" is the correct way of putting it. It is initialized to all 0s.

Answer (score 0):

The array num[] is not initialized. So, `sq[i] = num[i] * num[i];` has a problem because num[i] does not exist (There is no value there). Other than that, the code looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Some problems:**

- You don't need arrays
- You probably need 2 loops
- You're printing at the wrong place
- You don't need `sum`
- You're never setting the values of `num`. When you say

  ```
  int num[] = new int[10];
  ```

  All the values in the array will be initialized to 0 (or `null` if we were dealing with objects), that's what Java does (for that matter, no language I know of will automatically set the values of an array to auto-incremented values, unless explicitly told to do so).

**Hint:**

```
int max = 10;

for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++)
  /* Print each cell of the header row here */

for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++)
{
  /* Print the first column of a row */
  for (int j = 1; j <= max; j++)
    /* Print each cell for this row, which will be (i*i + j*j) */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO your problem is you *have* arrays: You don't need them.

Use iterative logic, in this case replacing `num[i]` with simply `i` (or similar). The solution is about getting the loop(s) right.